Databricks Bundle Assets create a job
Using databricks asset bundle, I want to use a job as a YAML file, and be able to duplicate it by changing the name of the job while deploying it using azure devops.
For example here is the content of my YAML file which is used to create the job in databricks
# ressource yaml file
resources:
   jobs:
    my-test-bundle_job:
    name: test-bundle_job
    tasks:
        - task_key: notebook_task
            job_cluster_key: job_cluster
            notebook_task:
                notebook_path: ../src/simple_notebook.ipynb
    job_clusters:
        - job_cluster_key: job_cluster
            new_cluster:
                node_type_id: i3.xlarge
                spark_version: 13.3.x-scala2.12

I want to make the the key 'my-test-bundle_job' a variable to give while deploying.
The other solution might be to duplicate an existing databricks job (yml file) with a given name.

Can you achieve your requirement locally using Dataricks CLI and some scripts? If so, please share the commands/scripts you used. Then I can try to help you do the same in the DevOps pipeline.

Hi @Khalil Fall, have you tried Replace Tokens task? Did it work for you?

You can use Replace Tokens task. See the details below.

Set the $(varname) in the databricks.yml file in your Azure repo. For example,

bundle:
  name: baby-names

resources:
  jobs:
    $(jobkey):
      name: retrieve-filter-baby-names-job
      job_clusters:
        - job_cluster_key: common-cluster
...


Add a variable named jobkey in your DevOps pipeline. Its value will automatically replace $(jobkey) in your databricks.yml file when running replacetokens@6 task.

variables:
  jobkey: mytestjobkey


Add replacetokens@6 task before databricks bundle validate.

- task: replacetokens@6
  inputs:
    root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    sources: 'databricks.yml'
    tokenPattern: 'azpipelines'
    addBOM: true
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      databricks bundle validate -t development
      databricks bundle deploy -t development

Then you can see your target jobkey in the databricks.yml file deployed to your Databricks workspace.


Thanks for this clear answer.
I tried it but I am face an error saying that 'A task is missing'.

Can you share more details about "A task is missing"?  Replace Tokens task is a third-party task, you need to install it from the marketplace if you haven't downloaded it yet.

yeap the reason is that I have not installed it from marketplace.
I will have first to check if my company allows installation from tiers source.

Feel free to check. It would be easy to replace the job key if you can install this extension.
